# Proper usage of <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, Im currently developing a prototype system for a requirement in my degree.

My question is how do you use the code ? it seems like it only caters to one html file that I originally coded it.

To be more specific:
I already called the code  to power my real time calendar and clock for this specific schedule.html file 
I used the same line  to another adddate.html file to produce a confirm box but for some reason the confirmation box is working on the schedule.html file not in the adddate.html file

can anyone help? please go easy on me im still learning its only been 1 and half weeks of coding...

FAQS: 
Yes, They are in the same file folder for anchor href purposes (prototype still)
No, I haven't read everything there is to know about javascripting (sorry...)
thanks in advance!

Comment: You really only need `<script>`.

Comment: To be able to code properly, one need to read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are writing the js code inline all you need is

```
<script>
  // code goes here
</script>
```

Otherwise you need the source (src) attribute if you are pointing to a file

```
<script src="/file-name.js"></script>
```

Javascript is the default so you don't need the `type` or `language` attributes. Also the `src` attribute is the relative location so if you need to change directories, `../directory/file-name.js` - as an example.

Hope that helps.